# Подсчет повторяющихся элементов в коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции

Необходимо подсчитать количество повторений элементов в коллекции. Подсчитывает все правильно, но выводит в консоль столько раз, сколько элементов в массиве. Не пойму как исправить.

```java
public class Array {
    public static int countWords(ArrayList<String> WordsArr, String word) {
        return Collections.frequency(WordsArr, word);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> WordsArr = new ArrayList<>();
        WordsArr.add("Франция");
        WordsArr.add("Германия");
        WordsArr.add("Монако");
        WordsArr.add("Испания");
        WordsArr.add("Италия");
        WordsArr.add("Австрия");
        WordsArr.add("Испания");
        WordsArr.add("Монако");
        WordsArr.add("Грузия");
        WordsArr.add("Монако");
        WordsArr.add("Испания");
        WordsArr.add("Италия");
        WordsArr.add("Монако");
        WordsArr.add("Сингапур");
        WordsArr.add("Армения");

        System.out.println("Наш массив " + WordsArr);

        for (int i = 0; i < WordsArr.size(); i++) {
            if (countWords(WordsArr, WordsArr.get(i)) == 1) {
                System.out.println(" Уникальные слова " + WordsArr.get(i));
                System.out.println("Слово Испания повторяется " +
                        Collections.frequency(WordsArr, "Испания"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вынести System.out.println из цикла?

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло)

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 1):

Можно из листа строк собрать `Map<String, Integer>` и просуммировать количество вхождений:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
        "Франция", "Германия", "Монако", "Испания", "Италия",
        "Австрия", "Испания", "Монако", "Грузия", "Монако",
        "Испания", "Италия", "Монако", "Сингапур", "Армения");

Map<String, Integer> frequency = list.stream()
        // собираем элементы листа в карту
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // ключ - строка
                e -> e,
                // значение - число,
                // количество вхождений
                e -> 1,
                // суммируем количество вхождений
                Integer::sum));

// Выводим значение по ключу
System.out.println("Испания: " + frequency.get("Испания")); // Испания: 3

// Обходим карту и выводим содержимое
frequency.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
// Италия: 2
// Франция: 1
// Австрия: 1
// Армения: 1
// Монако: 4
// Испания: 3
// Грузия: 1
// Сингапур: 1
// Германия: 1
```

---

См. [Как посчитать количество элементов в массиве String, используя Map](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1212505/419011)

Comment: Ваш `toMap` лучше (с точки зрения чтения кода) заменить на `.groupingBy` таким образом : `Map<String, Long> frequency = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));`

Answer (score 1):

Вариант решения, предложенный в комментариях:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
        "Франция", "Германия", "Монако", "Испания", "Италия",
        "Австрия", "Испания", "Монако", "Грузия", "Монако",
        "Испания", "Италия", "Монако", "Сингапур", "Армения");

Map<String, Long> frequency =
        list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

frequency.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
```

Вывод:

```
Италия: 2
Франция: 1
Австрия: 1
Армения: 1
Монако: 4
Испания: 3
Грузия: 1
Сингапур: 1
Германия: 1
```