# Как посчитать количество элементов в массиве String, используя Map

Tags: java, массивы, map

Нужно посчитать сколько одинаковых элементов в строке

```
String[] parts = new String[]{
        "1S01", "1S01", "1S01", "1S01", "1S01", "1S02", "1S02",
        "1S02", "1H01", "1H01", "1S02", "1S01", "1S01", "1H01",
        "1H01", "1H01", "1S02", "1S02", "1M02", "1M02", "1M02"};
```

При этом каждому ID дано своё название в Map

```
Map<String, String> productNames = new TreeMap<>();
productNames.put("Blue Polo Shirt", "1S01");
productNames.put("Black Polo Shirt", "1S02");
productNames.put("Red Ball Cap", "1H01");
productNames.put("Duke Mug", "1M02");
```

Как посчитать сколько, к примеру Blue polo Shirt, используя Map?

Comment: Простейший вариант - завести словарь, где ключ - строка, значение - количество повторений.

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно из двух коллекций собрать одну карту `Map<String, Long>` с названиями и количеством:

```java
String[] parts = new String[]{
        "1S01", "1S01", "1S01", "1S01", "1S01", "1S02", "1S02",
        "1S02", "1H01", "1H01", "1S02", "1S01", "1S01", "1H01",
        "1H01", "1H01", "1S02", "1S02", "1M02", "1M02", "1M02"};

Map<String, String> productNames = new TreeMap<>();
productNames.put("Blue Polo Shirt", "1S01");
productNames.put("Black Polo Shirt", "1S02");
productNames.put("Red Ball Cap", "1H01");
productNames.put("Duke Mug", "1M02");

Map<String, Long> productParts = productNames.entrySet().stream()
        // собираем общую карту
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // ключ - название продукта
                product -> product.getKey(),
                // значение - количество
                // элементов в массиве
                product -> Arrays.stream(parts)
                        // отбираем элементы массива,
                        // соответвтвующие значению
                        // из карты продуктов
                        .filter(part -> part.equals(product.getValue()))
                        // считаем количество
                        .count()));

productParts.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
// Duke Mug: 3
// Red Ball Cap: 5
// Black Polo Shirt: 6
// Blue Polo Shirt: 7
System.out.println("Blue Polo Shirt: " + productParts.get("Blue Polo Shirt"));
// Blue Polo Shirt: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно посчитать количество вхождений в массиве и составить из них карту. Две карты будет. Одна с названиями, другая с количествами. Чтобы получить количество по названию, нужно будет два раза метод `get` выполнить:

```java
Map<String, String> productNames = new TreeMap<>();
productNames.put("Blue Polo Shirt",  "1S01");
productNames.put("Black Polo Shirt", "1S02");
productNames.put("Red Ball Cap",     "1H01");
productNames.put("Duke Mug",         "1M02");

String[] parts = new String[]{
        "1S01", "1S01", "1S01", "1S01", "1S01", "1S02", "1S02",
        "1S02", "1H01", "1H01", "1S02", "1S01", "1S01", "1H01",
        "1H01", "1H01", "1S02", "1S02", "1M02", "1M02", "1M02"};

Map<String, Integer> occurrences = Arrays.stream(parts)
        // собираем элементы массива в карту
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // ключ - строка,
                // элемент массива
                e -> e,
                // значение - число, суммируем
                // количество вхождений
                e -> 1, Integer::sum));

System.out.println(occurrences); // {1S02=6, 1S01=7, 1M02=3, 1H01=5}

// получаем количество по названию, почти INNER JOIN получается
int bps = occurrences.get(productNames.get("Blue Polo Shirt"));

System.out.println("Blue Polo Shirt: " + bps); // Blue Polo Shirt: 7
```